# Running druid script for injestion spec failed - bin/post-index-task --file quickstart/tutorial/wikipedia-index.json

Tags: druid, data-ingestion

I am trying to follow the quickstart for running the script but it is failing with this error in druid router cli:

```
~ $ bin/post-index-task --file quickstart/tutorial/wikipedia-index.json
bin/post-index-task: /opt/druid/bin/post-index-task-main: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
bin/post-index-task: line 31: /opt/druid/bin/post-index-task-main: No error information
```

`bin/post-index-task` is already present but it seem to throw an error of `No such file or directory`.

Please guide, thanks.

Comment: Found the same [question](https://www.druidforum.org/t/getting-an-error-while-running-spec-script-task/7978). It looks like python might not be available in the docker instance you used?

Comment: What will be the solution for it? I have not received any answer projecting the solution on druid forum as well.

Comment: The docker image is missing python which is needed to run that tutorial/script.